# SharePoint page refresh on server control click

Tags: sharepoint-server, c-sharp

I created a page with server side `radiobutton` and `checkbox` functionalities. But selecting every control, the page is refreshing. In this regard request to help me by suggesting an idea for rectifying this problem.

Comment: What type of page is that, an application,  a site page or a publishing page?

Comment: May i know if you are using AutoPostBack=True on the controls?

Comment: yes AutoPostBack=true .. because of cascading dropDowns on page.

Comment: Asad:  m working on a visual WebPart